# Safely access and parse a bool from a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have an application that uses a `Dictionary<String,String>` to store configuration.

I want to:

1. Check if the dictionary contains "Key"
2. Parse the Value of "Key" as a bool
3. Default to false if not found

Presently I am doing the following

```
bool settingBool = false
if (configDictionary.ContainsKey("Key")) {
   bool.Tryparse(configDictionary["Key"], out settingBool)
}
// Do some stuff with settingBool
```

Are there any pitfalls or obvious issues with the above approach especially from a readability/maintainability aspect?

Comment: Don't store them as `string`, use `bool` instead? Or if you need multiple types, use `object` and cast. Having said that, I would have wrapped this dictionary into it's own settings class in the first place so consumers of it never have to know what to do.

Comment: In what way cleaner?

Comment: What's the point of parsing the string as a boolean  ? I mean you can do a `Dictionary<string,string,bool>`

Comment: I've posted an answer but, now that I think about it, "cleaner" is a matter of opinion anyway.  I'm not sure that this is a valid question unless you can provide some criteria for "cleaner".

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to load configuration as an object instead of dictionary?

Comment: It is clean enough (and also is a good way to keep multiple parameters in a 2 column table - I think this is backed up by a database having 2 columns like ParameterID, Value - String is the common data type for many databases).

Comment: My guess is that, by "cleaner", you mean a single method call. If that is the case then the answer would be "no".

Comment: Actually, I think you could do this for a one-liner: `bool settingBool = "true".Equals(configDictionary.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == "Key")?.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`. Is that cleaner? That's debatable.

Comment: Thank you to the people who provided constructive responses.  Unfortunate (due to reasons that would be too complex to detail here) I am stuck with Dictionary<String,String> but I do note the responses that suggest other ways of sorting the data. I have edited to make the question more objective but put simply I am a novice at c# and wanted to learn if there was a better way of solving this problem given my initial implementation didn't leave me with a warm fuzzy feeling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one liner is needed or adding if the value parseable as bool then you can use && :

```
bool settingBool = false;
if (configDictionary.ContainsKey("Key") && bool.TryParse(configDictionary["Key"], out settingBool)
{

}
else {} // what if not? Then wouldn't you accept as false?
```

If default would be false when not found or not parseable to bool:

```
bool settingBool = false;
settingBool = configDictionary.ContainsKey("Key") && 
        bool.TryParse(configDictionary["Key"], out settingBool) 
        && settingBool;
```

The latter could be used to get with Linq to get multiple bool settings.

Note: bool.TryParse can parse limited strings as bools (it doesn't parse Yes, No, Y/N, 1/0 ... as bools).

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any pitfalls or obvious issues with the above approach especially from a readability/maintainability aspect?

As an addition to [@Cetin Basoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894977/cetin-basoz) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155605/5893316).

---

Since you want to do something with your `settingsBool` I personally would go with `configDictionary.TryGetValue("Key", out value)`, because

> **[TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)**
>
> This method combines the functionality of the ContainsKey method and the Item[TKey] property.

So for your example:

```
var configDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>() { { "Key" , "Value"} };

string value;
bool settingBool; 
if ( configDictionary.TryGetValue("Key", out value) 
     && bool.TryParse(value, out settingBool) )
{
    // Do something with your settingBool
}
else
{
    // Do something if "Key" is not present or Value could not be parsed.
}
```

---

*Hint: You did not need to set your `settingBool` to `false`, since `false` is the default value. Try `default(bool)`*